# How to best count nested objects in Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a Groovy class which looks a lot like this:

```
class A {

    B[] requests = []

}
```

In code, I have an array of A and I'd like to know how many B are contained within it. What's the most groovyish way to make that calculation? I know how to do it in Java, but it looks far uglier than I suspect Groovy would like it to be. Here's what I've worked out so far:

```
list.each{ a -> count += a.requests.size() }
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [spread operator (`*`)](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SpreadOperator%28%2a.%29)

```
class A {
    B[] requests = []
}

class B{
    String name
}

assert [
     new A(requests : [new B(name: 'John'), new B(name: 'Jim'), 
                       new B(name: 'Alex')]), 
     new A(requests : [new B(name: 'Test'), new B(name: 'Alex')]), 
     new A(requests : [new B(name: 'John')])
]*.requests*.size() == [3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Don't know, because it's pretty cool. I've just never used anything like it in any other language. My Java background interfering again, I guess.

Comment: You will find more and more cool and fun stuff once acquainted with it. You can go through some of the questions under groovy tag in Stackoverflow itself to witness some of its coolness. :) Stay Groovy.

Answer (score 2):

When coding this, I'd invoke [the KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) regarding maintenance and clarity. Not everything should use shiny features.

Your version is reasonably 'Groovy', though you may want to consider using the implicit variable `it` ([see doc](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures)):

```
def count = 0
list.each{ count += it.requests.size() }
```